# Create Partitions on MacBook Pro

Tags: partitioning, virtualization, macbook-pro

Is it possible to create a Windows 10 partition on a MacBook Pro? I'm thinking of getting a new MacBook Pro, but I need to run Windows 10. Within Windows 10, I need to be able to run Docker and Hyper-V. For that reason, I need to ensure that I can enable virtualization.

Nested virtualization via Parallels sounds too slow from a performance perspective. Bootcamp doesn't seem to work in this regard (I have a 2015 MBP and I can't get virtualization enabled even with the restart trick). Either way, I'd like to get as close to the metal as possible to get the performance. For that reason, I'm wondering if there's a way to simply create a separate Windows 10 partition.

Answer (score 0):

> For that reason, I'm wondering if there's a way to simply create a
>   separate Windows 10 partition.

You should install Windows on your MacBook Pro by using Boot Camp.

> Boot Camp Assistant guides you through installing Windows on your Mac.
>   Open this app from the Utilities folder inside the Applications
>   folder. Then follow the onscreen instructions to repartition your
>   startup disk and download related software drivers for Windows.

[How to install Windows on your Mac with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468)

Comment: In the event you don't know how to install Windows through Boot Camp, [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990#newinstall), are the instructions to do so.  I am leaving the instructions as a comment, to avoid having to quote and cite, an entire Apple support article.